# Groovy: comparing items from 2 different lists having different format

Tags: arraylist, groovy, compare, jenkins-groovy

I've a list

```
def a = [kitkat lollypop orea android-11]
```

another list

```
def b = ["kitkat", "lollypop", "honeycomb", "nougat", "android-11"]
```

I need to do some task on list a items if they exist in list b if they don't exist in list b then do something else.

One thing to note is list a items are separated by space and no quotes whereas list be is by comma and has items within quotes; due to this things I've tried below did not work.

I've tried the following:
1)

```
a.split(" ").each{
    def itema = it
    b.split(",").each{
        if(b.contains(itema){
            //do something
        }
    }
    //do something else
)
```

2. 

```
a.split(" ").each{
    if(b.split(",").contains(it){
        //do something
    }
    //do something else
}
```

3. 

```
for(itema in a){
    for(itemb in b){
        if(itema == itemb){
            //do something
        }
    }
    //do something else
}
```

4. 

```
a.intersect(b)
```

but this threw exception due to list a having spaces between elements

I think what I want is create a new list from list a by changing it to have comma separated items with quotes and then could use one of the above solution
or is there a better way to do in groovy what I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there in examples 1 and 2, but there are a few issues.

I'm going to assume this:

```
def a = [kitkat lollypop orea android-11]
```

is actually a String, based on how you're attempting to split it. In my solution I'm going to assume it's this:

```
def a = "[kitkat lollypop orea android-11]"
```

Using the String in 'a', take everything between the two brackets. From there, split the String by the space character in order to get a list of items. Then, using this new items list, we're going to go one by one and iterate through list b to see if we have any matches:

```
def items = a.takeBetween("[", "]")
items.split(/\s/).each {
   if (it in b) {
      println "I'm in list b - $it"
   } else {
      println "I'm not in list b - $it"
   }
}
```

This will result in:

```
I'm in list b - kitkat
I'm in list b - lollypop
I'm not in list b - orea
I'm in list b - android-11
```